# Problem with docx2tex custom configuration

Tags: citing, conversion, xml, word-to-latex

I'm trying to improve conversion of my `DOCX` files with ZOTERO citation. My idea was to set custom citation format, to mimic tex style, so after the conversion to tex, I will have only to set my BIB file, without any manual changes in text. So the examplary citation looks as follows (still in `DOCX` file):

```
Here is a text in docx format with a styled citation \cite{author_date_word}
```

When I run docx2tex, I recive in `TEX`:

```
Here is a text in docx format with a styled citation \textbackslash cite\{author_date_word\}
```

As the docx2tex escape "problematic" characters and mess my attempt. In this particular case I want to have it kept in unchanged form. Regarding to documentation I have to disable it in `conf.xml`. I was successfully using this file to change simple things, like default imported library list, heading format etc. But as I'm xml newbie, I can't figure out the way to disable above mentioned replacement. Could you explain me how to do this?